# Can I use camber bolts on my 2013 Suzuki Splash?

Tags: suzuki, alignment, camber

I need to adjust the camber on my 2013 Suzuki Splash, and the current bolts do not allow for camber adjustment. The only ones I found for Suzuki Splash anywhere are these: https://shopeibach.co.uk/collections/suzuki-splash-2008-2011/products/eibach-front-camber-bolts-5-81250k

In the online shops they are sold, it says they are only compatible with Suzuki Splash made from 2008-11. Can anybody tell me if they will still fit or not or how I should adjust the camber if they don't? My VIN number is TSMEXB32S00739269.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Why is it you need to adjust your camber? The camber is set from the factory and shouldn't change. The only time something gets out of camber is if there is something physically wrong with the vehicle (ie: in need of repair or replacement parts).

Comment: Hi @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, thanks for the reply. I need to change it because my front tyres have been wearing on the inside more than the outside (back tyres are fine). I heard the vehicle can be knocked out of alignment sometimes if you drive through some holes, etc.

Comment: Wrong toe adjustment will cause the same wear and is the most likely thing to be out.  Have you taken the vehicle to get the alignment adjusted?  You may also have a worn ball joint.

Comment: Hi @HandyHowie, thanks for the reply. I just measured the toe myself with the string method and the car is toeing out a bit, explaining the tyre wear on the inside. I will take this to the alignment shop. Regarding the ball joint, I just replaced one of them last year (but not the other one), can one worn out ball joint cause toe on both sides (both front tyres are wearing on the inside, not just one)?

Comment: Yes, one faulty ball joint can cause wear on both front tyres.